# how to prevent delete last char from input

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to prevent deleting the last char from the input. So imagine we have an input with some value-added by user in our page. We have a button to edit this input. So I would like to prevent a user from removing the last char from the input.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you try to provide some code?

Comment: onchange handler with prevent the default if its last character?